# How to calculate price in column based on additional criterias?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, business-logic, stored-functions

How do I calculate final price in table **items** based on criterias? Criterias would be set in table **modifier**. I was thinking about left join but is it possible in stored procedure to choose type of modifier? Every records would have only one criteria, they cant be combined.

**items:**

```
code   |   price_general
---------------------------------
BIKE   |   50
CAR    |   300
BOAT   |   600
PLANE  |   1200
```

**modifier:**

```
type   |   item        |  amount
----------------------------------
PERC   |   CAR         |  20   (add 20% on top)
FIXE   |   BOAT        |  700  (fixed price 700)
ADD    |   PLANE       |  10   (add +10 value)
```

result should look like this

```
code   |   price_general    |    price_final
-------------------------------------------------
BIKE   |   50               |    50
CAR    |   300              |    360
BOAT   |   600              |    700
PLANE  |   1200             |    1210
```

Is this possible in TSQL? Or should I add additional business logic to C# code?

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [CASE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) with your logic. Something like:

```
SELECT i.code, i.price_general,
price_final = 
CASE m.type  
WHEN 'PERC' THEN i.price_general*(1 + m.amount/100)
WHEN 'FIXE' THEN m.amount
WHEN 'ADD' THEN i.price_general + m.amount
ELSE i.price_general
END
FROM items i LEFT JOIN modifier m on i.item = m.code;
```

Apologies for any typos or syntax errors, I use Postgresql, but I hope you get the idea...

Comment: Works well (after minor modification for TSQL). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

split the amt into up and fixed
just put 0 in up if you want all fixed
and 0 in fixed if you want all up

```
select items.code
     , items.price_general 
     , isnull(modifier.item, items.price_general, items.price_general * modifier.up + modifier.fixed) as [price_final]
  from items 
  left join modifier 
    on modifier.item = items.code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT I.CODE,
       I.PRICE_GENERAL,
       CASE
         WHEN M.TYPE LIKE 'ADD%[%]%' THEN I.PRICE_GENERAL * ( 1 + M.AMOUNT / 100 )
         WHEN M.TYPE LIKE 'FIXED%' THEN M.AMOUNT
         WHEN M.TYPE LIKE 'ADD%'
              AND M.TYPE NOT LIKE 'ADD%[%]%' THEN I.PRICE_GENERAL + M.AMOUNT
         ELSE I.PRICE_GENERAL
       END
FROM   ITEMS I
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MODIFIER M
                    ON I.ITEM = M.CODE
```